# Binding Setter.Value from code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind, setter

In XAML I can write something like this:

```
<Setter Property="PropertyName" Value="{Binding ...}" />
```

How would I do this in code? I've constructed bindings in code before, but I can't seem to find any static `ValueProperty` object on the `Setter` class to pass to `BindingOperations.SetBinding()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When setting a binding on a Setter you don't need BindingOperations at all.  All you need to do is:

```
var setter = new Setter(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("FirstName"));
```

or equivalently

```
var setter = new Setter
{
  Property = TextBlock.TextProperty,
  Value = new Binding("FirstName"),
};
```

either of these would be equivalent to

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding FirstName}" />
```

The reason this works is that Setter.Value is an ordinary CLR property, not a DependencyProperty and as such it can't be bound.  So there is no ambiguity in either the XAML or the code when you store a Binding object in it.

When the Setter is actually applied to an object, if a Binding is found in the Setter, the equivalent of BindingOperations.SetBinding is called.  Otherwise the property is set directly.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. It seemed odd to me that there was no ValueProperty in Setter, but I never thought of just setting the value *to* a Binding object. :) Cheers Ray--you've been helping me a lot lately. ;)